# Why symmetry works here?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Prove that $$\frac{a^2}{(b-c)^2}
> +\frac{b^2}{(c-a)^2}
> +\frac{c^2}{(a-b)^2}>2$$ for all non-negative real $a,b,c$, no two of which are equal.

In the [official solution](https://www2.cms.math.ca/Competitions/CMO/archive/sol2017.pdf) they used symmetry. They replaced $(a,b,c)=(a-c,b-c,0)$
but why this kind of symmetry holds true? Also in an alternative solution,it did really big multiplication like expanding $(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2$ and also expanded $[a(a-b)(b-c)+b(b-c)(c-a)+c(c-a)(c-b)]^2$

My question is how can I do these manipulations. Also, I almost know nothing of symmetric inequalities can anyone describe me what this technique is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When approaching symmetric problems like this, often at some point you do something to break the symmetry (and then, if required by the problem, you show how your solution propagates across the symmetries). So here they assume that $a \leq b \leq c \leq 0$ by just noting that rearranging the terms in order of descending numerator doesn't change the result.

The next step comes about by trying to restrict the possible set of $(a, b, c)$ without changing the minimum value. Compare the left-hand side of the inequality before and after the replacement:

$$\frac{(a-c)^2}{(b-c)^2} + \frac{(b-c)^2}{(a-c)^2} + \frac{0^2}{(a-b)^2} \leq \frac{a^2}{(b-c)^2} + \frac{b^2}{(a-c)^2} + \frac{c^2}{(a-b)^2}$$

Using the fact that $a \geq c \geq 0 \implies a \geq a - c \geq 0 \implies a^2 \geq (a-c)^2$, and similarly for $b$. So that means that for any input $(a, b, c)$, you can make the left-hand side smaller (or at least not-bigger) by using the input $(a-c,b-c,0)$. This means the minimum must occur when $c = 0$ (because if it happened when $c > 0$, you could do that transformation and get a value smaller than the minimum).

Comment: Yes, thank you for your nice description. But in the official solution, there is an alternative solution. In that solution,  How can I expand those extremely large products? And how do they complete the square?

Comment: @MontasirAhmed Proving the identity in hindsight (IE when you know the terms) is easy, you just expand everything. Note that the square terms are just the individual terms, so we only need to account for the cross terms. $\quad$ Coming up with the identity is much harder. That could come from experience or wishful thinking.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately for a lot of these things the answer to "How do I know to apply this trick?" is "Because I've seen it or a similar trick used before". Although things like "What's an easier version of the problem I can solve?" and "Can I assume something then check whether the assumption is valid?" are also handy things to ask yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The $(a,b,c)\to (a-c,b-c,0)$ replacement has nothing to do with symmetry. Symmetry is used only to realise that the expression $E=\frac{a^2}{(b-c)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(c-a)^2}+\frac{c^2}{(a-b)^2}$ is invariant under the $a\to b\to c\to a$ replacement. This fact is used to claim that no generality is lost in assuming $a>b>c$.

The other steps are to find out some other expression (say $E^\prime$) smaller than $E$ yet still larger than $2$. This will prove that $E>E^\prime$ and $E^\prime>2$ which will prove $E>2$ as we wanted.

Two such steps are to first use $(a,b,c)\to (a-c,b-c,0)$ which lowers the numerator without changing the denominator, and then to put $c=0$ which again can only lower the left hand side expression.

I hope the solution is clear to you now.